# Regarding efficient use of break statement in java

Tags: java

In the infinite loop I'm using break statement after some particular condition till now there is no issue but i'm afraid of future because the program is running continuously 24*7 hrs and in the loop itself there is almost 2000 lines of code.

So whether I shall use break statement or I have to handle it with different way.
Any good idea ?

```
while(true){
 ....
    if(true)
        break;
   .
   .

}
```

Comment: put some code in your question.

Comment: There is no other way to handle break statements in java. if you want to break out of the loop, you break out.

Comment: Having 2000 lines of code in a loop may be an indication that you should split a method down into smaller, testable parts. But a break statement is a perfectly decent way of exiting a loop (of any size).

Comment: 2KLOC inside a loop? That may be an opportunity for some [refactoring](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method).

Comment: "whether i shall use break statement or i have to handle it with different way"
Totally depends on your usecase. If you have little or no memory leak, running an infinte loop should be okay. But we cannot comment on whether the design is good or not unless we know the usecase.

Comment: An infinite loop itself is usually a smell unless you specifically do some sort of sleeping in it. By itself this question is unanswerable beyond "why on earth does *any* single unit of code have 2000 *anything* in it?!?!"

Comment: We understand what a `break` statement is.

Comment: `if(false) break;` unreachable `break` my friend.

Comment: Dave Newton What do mean ... whether you got my question or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using infinite loop is a bad design. All the more when the control hits break statement the loop is no more infinite. Are you using infinite loop to make the program run continuously 24/7. if thats the purpose you can use [Java service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html) instead of infinite loops.

Comment: In the first question you said that you have a break statement in an infinite loop. Now you are giving an example of a loop inside another loop.   Are you asking our suggestions here or trying to prove that you have done something perfect?

Comment: you were right i had some doubt about the break point thats why i asked but i never mean to show that i did something perfect.